# sigma.js : error on adding Graph Node. ERROR: Uncaught The node "159684" already exists

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sigma.js

[image]I have neo4j graph database. I am trying to get neighbors of a node by clicking on the node . But when I get the nodes and try to add them the node clicked is already present so it returns error. I am sure after this is solved it will also give error on AddEdge as well.
Any ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @ Michael Hunger I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Here it's a sigma error : you are trying to add a node into the sigma graph model that already exist, and this operation is not allow.

In fact when you load the neighbours of a node, there is a chance that one neighbours already display on sigma (ie. the node is alreay loaded into the graph model).

To avoid this, before to call the graph.addNode() function, you should check if the node is not already there by calling `graph.nodes(id)`. This function will give you the corresponding node if it exist.

Cheers.